# Creating a class for a specific json to be passed from view to controller

Tags: c#, json, model-view-controller

This is the json structure im using in frontend, where the "books" is an array so it can contain multiple values.

```
{
   "name":"",
   "surname":"",
   "books":
     [
        { "book_name": "", "book_rating": "" },
        { "book_name": "", "book_rating": "" }
     ]
}
```

Should i create a class with a list of a 2 variables class?

or can i recieve the json as string and then converting it into json again in the controller?

Thx for the help

Comment: You can do both. Try both options out, see which one works better for you. Only you know which is "better".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should i create a class with a list of a 2 variables class?

In my opinion after reading JSon file you should start using your own created classes instead of using just the plain string. You have to turn JSon string into objects anyhow to process in controller classes. So here are two classes that may come in handy for you:

```
public class User
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string surname { get; set; }
    public List<Book> books { get; set; }
}

public class Book
{
    public string book_name { get; set; }
    public int book_rating { get; set; }
}
```

Here how you will use your classes

```
        // open and read JSon file into jsonString

        // Convert json string into an object
        var user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(jsonString);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change to this if you want to send it to the controller:

```
var data = {
   name:"",
   surname:"",
   books:
     [
      book:  { book_name: "", book_rating : "" },
      book:  {}
     ]
};
```